# Is there a way to load information from a properties file that is outside a project's directory when the project gets exported as a JAR?

Tags: java

I need to keep database credentials in a properties file that is located outside of my project's folder/structure/class paths (i.e. C:/Parent_name/config/config.properties). The project (C:/Parent_name/Tomcat/Project_name/) gets exported as a JAR and is used in other applications (C:/Tomcat/webapps/app_1/WEB-INF/lib/Project_name.jar) that are then deployed to a Tomcat server.

I've found I can't do a simple FileInputStream because the file would need to be a part of the class path and I need the file to be outside of the project so DBA's can easily update credentials when needed. getResourceAsSteam() returns a null pointer exception.

Here's two examples of code that don't achieve what I need:

FileInputSteam

```
private static Object readConfigFile()  {

    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Parent_name\\config\\config.properties")) {

        Properties prop = new Properties();

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.url"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.user"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.password"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

getResrouceAsSteam()

```
private static Object readConfigFile() {
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName("SQLCredentials");

            // returns the ClassLoader object associated with this Class
            ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
            InputStream input = cLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:/Parent_name/config/config.properties");

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.url"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.user"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("db.password"));
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use a resource. You would probably actually use a normal File. Maybe check for a file in the users folder, if it doesn't exist create one they can populate.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you can't use a normal `FileInputStream`, that's what they're for--file input streams, says so in the docs: "obtains input bytes from a file in a file system". What you have now, a resource, must be in the project class path. Your first example is not a `FileInputStream`, it's a resource stream.

Comment: “I can't do a simple FileInputStream because the file would need to be a part of the class path” Actually, the opposite is true.  A resource must be in the classpath or module path;  a FileInputStream is literally intended for reading any (readable) file on the file system.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry for the confusion. I put the wrong code for the FileInputStream. The correct example is there now. I tried the path with /'s as well. Same File not found exception. From what I gathered, it can't be found because the code is being exported as a JAR. Am I wrong about these findings? Should the JAR still be able to look up that path no matter what machine it's on so long as that file exists?

Comment: @VGR see above comment, not sure why I can't tag two people at the same time.

Comment: @PaulSender Can you use a relative path like "db.properties"? Then it would look for such a file in the working directory you are using.

Comment: Whether or not the code is in a jar is irrelevant; file paths are file paths: if the file exists and the user has access to it it should work fine. If it *doesn't* then something else is wrong.

Comment: Whether Java code is running in a .jar file has no bearing on the ability to read a regular file in the file system.  Consider using [Files.newInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) instead of FileInputStream, as the former will give you a more informative exception if, for example, the file is present but your program doesn’t have permission to read it.

Comment: The standard way to provide database credentials to a web application is to configure a datasource in the server (Tomcat in your case) and use JNDI.

Comment: @VGR I tried with newInputStream. There's an issue with the file not being found even though the path I'm using is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way to "Is there a way to load information from a properties file that is outside a project's directory when the project gets exported as a JAR?"

1. The project being exported as a JAR has no bearing on the ability to read a regular file in the file system as VGR pointed out in his very helpful comment.
2. My problem was the file not being found. The debug step I took to lead me to the correct answer was listing all files in a directory

```
     String[] pathnames;

     // Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
     // into an abstract pathname
     File f = new File("C:\\Parent_name\\config");

     // Populates the array with names of files and directories
     pathnames = f.list();

     // For each pathname in the pathnames array
     for (String pathname : pathnames) {
         // Print the names of files and directories
         System.out.println(pathname);
     }
```

Here I discovered that config.properties was actually config.properties.txt.

3. In order to create a proper config.properties file, I created a new file in eclipse, named it config.properties, then copy/pasted it into C://Parent_name//config. I used the following code to read the file and print it's values:

```
private static Object readConfigFile()  {

  
 try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:\\Parent_name\\config\\config.properties"))) {
    
     Properties prop = new Properties();

     // load a properties file
     prop.load(input);

     // get the property value and print it out
     System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dev.url"));
     System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dev.user"));
     System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dev.password"));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: When you are doing programming that involves files, it is a good idea to bring up a file explorer (Windows + E), then go to View, Options, then choose the View tab, and uncheck “Hide extensions for known file types.”  That will prevent Windows from tricking you into believing a file has a different name than the name it actually has.  Programmers need to know real filenames, not “prettified” names.